# Display image with relations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, relation, laravel-relations

I want to display through the user's photo relationships but it does not show
And this photo also exists, but when I take dd(), it says null
this is Blade code    And they all work except the user_image

```
 @foreach($threads as $thread)
                <div class="card my-3  rounded-lg mr-  ">
                    <div class="card-body shadow ">
                        <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
                            <div class=" d-flex">
                                <p style="font-size: x-large; font-weight: bold; "><a class="" href="/threads/{{$thread->slug}}">{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($thread->title,50)}}</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class=" d-flex">
                                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle mr-1 " style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"
                             
                                     src="{{$thread->user->user_image}}">      {{--    this is not working--}}
                                <p class="mt-3 text-secondary"
                                    توسط {{$thread->user->name}} آپدیت شد</p>
                            </div>
                            <footer
                                class="blockquote-footer text-dark">{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($thread->description,150)}}
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: You need to show the code, Model definition, relationship statement not just blade file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  replace

```
       public function user()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
     }

by something like

   public function images()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 }
```

and for users do

```
hasMany (images)
```

Also you have to do migrations to add foreign keys, did you do this ?